# How to fetch part of read only message in imap?

Tags: fetch, command, imap

What is the exact FETCH command that is used to read only the text body of message 1?

I tried this below and variations of it but it says BAD Error in IMAP and Unknown command.

```
**FETCH 1:1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (TEXT)]**
```

Im executing this in Ubuntu on a terminal for my upcoming exam.

Comment: That retrieves a header field called "text". Try it with "subject" instead of "text", you'll see what it does. Fetching `body[1]` retrieves the first bodypart, which may or may not be a text part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `_ FETCH 1 (BODY[TEXT])`. Why do you have asterisks around your command? You find the possible arguments to the `FETCH` command in [RFC 3501](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5). You can also play around with the [interactive tool](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#internet-message-access-protocol) that I wrote.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely check it out. The astecrics added themselves somehow when I copy and pasted the command from the terminal to stack overflow.

Comment: By the way, make sure to use a [tag](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-2.2.1) before the command. The `_` in my response is not a typo, but feel free to replace it with something else.